# How to write a python script to search a website html for matching links

Tags: python, scrape

I am not too familiar with python and have to write a script to perform a host of functions. 
Basically the module i still need is how to check a website code for matching links provided beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matching links what? Their HREF attribute? The link display text?
Perhaps something like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re
import urllib2

doc = urllib2.urlopen("http://somesite.com").read()
links = SoupStrainer('a', href=re.compile(r'^test'))
soup = [str(elm) for elm in BeautifulSoup(doc, parseOnlyThese=links)]
for elm in soup:
    print elm
```

That will grab the HTML content of `somesite.com` and then parse it using BeautifulSoup, looking only for links whose HREF attribute starts with "test". It then builds a list of these links and prints them out.

You can modify this to do anything using the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (htmllib etc) for programming web in Python. you could also use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), [curl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) etc. Then for processing HTML and getting links, you would want to use parsers like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup).

Answer (score 0):

try scrapy , the most comprehensive web extraction framework.

http://scrapy.org